# Symmetry condition of $\nabla X$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm currently calculating a bit in local coordinates and tensor calculus notation, which I'm new to.

I am given the vector field $X$ and the associated one form $\phi$ on a riemannian manifold with Levi-Civita connection. I want to show that $\nabla X$ is a symmetric if and only if $d\phi=0$.

My idea was to write the statements in local coordinates and simply transform the equations until i have a sequence of equivalece transformations. I got
$$ (\nabla_iX)^j=\partial_i X^j +\Gamma^j_{ik}X^k$$
and from $d\phi=0$ i can extract the following by using that the connection is metric.
\begin{align}
\partial_i X_l=\partial_jX_i&=\partial_j(g_{ik}X^k)\\
&=(\partial_j g_{ik})X^k+g_{ik}\partial_j X^k \\
&=(\Gamma ^l_{ji}g_{lk}+\Gamma^l_{jk}g_{il})X^k+g_{jk}\partial_j X^k
\end{align}
I tried to play around with these term, but it seems like I'm missing something crucial.

Comment: there are some typos in your coordinate expression for $\partial_i X_l$ which make it hard to check. Can you please fix them? (You start out with indicex $_{il}$, then it becomes $_{ji}$, then $_{jj}$, in the last line the $X^k$ term is missing in the first summand...)

Comment: Ty, should be fixed now. The first swap is becaus of the local expression of $0=d\phi=\partial_j X_i dx_j\wedge dx_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the derivative of the metric only complicates the matters. All we need
is its symmetry which leads to the symmetry of the Christoffel symbols in
their two lower indices.

\begin{align}
d\phi&=\partial_iX_j\,dx^i\wedge dx^j=\Big(\partial_iX_j-\partial_jX_i\Big)\,dx^i\otimes dx^j\,.
\end{align}
This vanishes identically if and only if all terms
$$
\partial_iX_j-\partial_jX_i
$$
vanish. These terms are equal to $\nabla_iX_j-\nabla_jX_i$ because
$$
\nabla_iX_j=\partial_iX_j-\Gamma^k_{ij}X_k
$$
and $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ is symmetric in $i,j$ (Levi-Civita connection).

In words: $d\phi$ vanishes identically if and only if $\partial_iX_j$ is symmetric or equivalently $\nabla_iX_j$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 5):

@KurtG.'s answer perfectly answers your concern.
I would like to give a coordinate-free approach to the question.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d} \newcommand{\dx}{\d \!}$
If $\phi$ is a $1$-form, its exterior derivative $\dx\phi$ satisfies
$$
\dx\phi(Y,Z) = Y\phi(Z) - Z\phi(Y) -\phi([Y,Z]),
$$
where $Y$ and $Z$ are vector fields.
If $\phi = g(X,\cdot)$ for a vector field $X$, recalling that the Levi-Civita connection is torsion-free, one has
\begin{align}
\dx\phi(Y,Z)
&= Yg(X,Z) - Zg(X,Y) -g(X,[Y,Z]) \\
&= g(\nabla_YX,Z) + g(X,\nabla_YZ) -g(\nabla_ZX,Y) - g(X,\nabla_ZY) -g(X,[Y,Z]) \\
&= g(\nabla_YX,Z) - g(\nabla_ZX,Y) +g(X,\nabla_YZ-\nabla_ZY-[Y,Z]) \\
&= g(\nabla_YX,Z) - g(\nabla_ZX,Y).
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\dx\phi= 0
&\iff \forall Y,Z, \quad g(\nabla_YX,Z) = g(\nabla_ZX,Y) \\
&\iff \nabla X \text{ is symmetric.}
\end{align}

---

I would like to add a short digression.
Like any other endomorphism, $\nabla X$ uniquely decomposes as $\nabla X = \nabla^+ X + \nabla^- X$, with $\nabla^+ X$ symmetric and $\nabla^- X$ skew-symmetric.
For vector fields $Y$ and $Z$, they read
\begin{align}
2g(\nabla^+_YX,Z)
&= g(\nabla_YX,Z) + g(Y,\nabla_ZX), \\
2g(\nabla^-_YX,Z)
&= g(\nabla_YX,Z) - g(Y,\nabla_ZX).
\end{align}
Playing around with the properties of the Levi-Civita connection as above, one easily verifies that
\begin{align}
2g(\nabla^+_YX,Z)
&= (\mathcal{L}_Xg)(Y,Z), \\
2g(\nabla^-_YX,Z)
&= \dx\phi^X(Y,Z),
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{L}_X$ is the Lie derivative in the direction of $X$ and $\phi^X$ is the dual form of $X$.
In particular, one has
$$
2g(\nabla_{\cdot} X,\cdot)
= \mathcal{L}_Xg + \dx\phi^X,
$$
which turns out to be...
exactly [Koszul's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry).
I always found this formula very obscure until I realized that.

Comment: This might be trivial but to someone like me it is interesting to see the duality of $d\phi=0\Longleftrightarrow \nabla X$ symmetric with $(\mathcal{L}_Xg)=0\Longleftrightarrow\nabla X$ anti-symmetric. The latter is the definition of $X$ being a Killing vector field.

Comment: @KurtG. I wouldn't say that it's trivial, but it is not *so* surprising. Given a metric $g$ and a vector field $X$, there are barely three $2$-tensors that one can build canonically: $\mathcal{L}_Xg$, $d\phi^X$, and $g(\nabla_{\cdot} X,\cdot)$, and one can then expect that they are somehow linked. The fact that the two first are *exactly* the symmetric and antisymmetric part of the third is what is "surprising" in my opinion